# Printing layout to set scale not working AcrGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, scale, printing

[image]When I set a scale of say 1:500 in a layout and then export it as a pdf and print OR also when I directly print layout from ArcGIS Pro, the printout is not exactly at 1:500.
I set the layout as A3 and the paper size as A3. It doesn't make a difference if I print at "actual" or "print to paper size".

Has someone experienced this and has workarounds?

EDIT: I believe the issue is that it prints a frame around the layout even though I expand the mapframe all the way to the edges of the layout. So when I measure the printed file it doesn't scale to the intended scale of 1:500.

Comment: In this particular case, I would recommend to add some screenshots of the process.

Comment: In ArcPro, I usually Share/Export Map, not Export Layout.

Comment: It prints to page size or actual the same because you are using all of the page. I doubt the map frame has anything to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out that it was actually in the printers settings that needed to be set to borderless printing and then when printing setting the sale to 100%.